# Displaying field's description in label or textbox on form

Tags: vba, ms-access

What I'd like to do is display the description from the currently selected field in a label on my form. I feel that where it is currently being displayed (the bottom left status bar) is barely noticeable.

How do I access that value in the status bar? For example, on my form, when I have a say, employee name field selected, in the bottom left in small print, it displays "The name of the employee you are registering."

I know in some event on my form, I need code that does

```
 me.lblControlDescription.Caption = me.statusbar.caption
```

How do I access the text in the status bar (the field description) in VBA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text in the status bar is the current field's `Description` property.

From VBA, you can access the `Description` of a field in the form's recordset.

```
Debug.Print Me.Recordset.fields("id").Properties("Description")
```

So, if you have a label control named `lblDescription`, you can set its `.Caption` value to the field's `Description`.

```
Me.lblDescription.Caption = Me.Recordset.fields("id").Properties("Description")
```

However, this could be more complicated.  `Description` is a user-created property, which means that it doesn't exist until you give it a value.  And, if you have one set, but delete its value later, the property itself no longer exists.

If you attempt to retrieve the `Description` when one doesn't exist, VBA will throw error #3270, "Property not found."  You could trap that error, and set `Me.lblDescription.Caption` to `vbNullString` when it happens.

You also need a strategy for *when* to change `Me.lblDescription.Caption`.  You could create a procedure to set it based on the current active control.  Then call that procedure from the on focus event of each of your form's controls.  There may be a better approach for this, but I'm not seeing one just now.

Comment: Thanks hans, I was under the impression that the description was actually being set as the value for the form (on change of active control), and could be accessed that way. Would Me.lblDescription.caption = Me.ActiveControl.Properties("description") be an effective solution? Edit: it is not

Comment: I'll guess no.  A field can have a Description property; a control does not.  Also plan your strategy to cope with unbound data controls as well as other controls (ie command button) for which Description is not available.