# Access: Displaying a list of (boolean) field names and descriptions if their value is true

Tags: forms, ms-access, field

I'm making a database in Access to manage our stock of chemical products and to keep a record of who uses them. I also want it to show some general information about the products.

Each chemical is associated with a number of [Hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GHS_hazard_statements) and [Precautionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GHS_precautionary_statements) statements.

I have a table 'Hazards', linked to a table 'Products' via the 'ProductNumber' field. In 'Hazards' there are a lot of Yes/No fields called H200, H201, H202,... with the statement as description. (I had to create a 'Hazards' and a 'Precautions' table and link it to the 'Products' table because Access has a limit of 255 fields per table)

What I want in my ProductForm (showing info for a specific product with a specific ProductNumber) is to have a textbox or a listbox or something containing all H- and P-statements which are true in the form of:

H206: Fire, blast or projection hazard: increased risk of explosion if desensitizing agent is reduced
H229: Pressurized container: may burst if heated

I think it can be done using a combination of
[Displaying field's description in label or textbox on form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12939843/displaying-fields-description-in-label-or-textbox-on-form/12940245#12940245)
and
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/429306-access-only-display-true-items-in-report but I don't really know where to start.

I also don't really know if this is the best way to organize such data, so if there is a better way please let me know :)

Answer (score 2):

Database design is an art, combined with a science.  There's a reason Database Architects get paid good money.  It's like trying to do Dentistry after watching a Youtube video.

However, I can give you a few pointers that will help.  First of all, you generally only want to write data once.  The less you have to touch data, the better off you are.  So, in that case, you'll want a table with nothing but Hazzards and their descriptions:

tblHazards:

```
HazardNumber    HazardDescription
H101            Fire hazard
H102            Compression hazard
etc....
```

Since the Hazard numbers are unique, the HazardNumber field will act as it's own "key".  If you have a table of non-unique data, then you should add an ID field to it to make it easy to reference.

Now you have your products table.  It would look something like this:

tblProducts:

```
ProductID      ProductName        Manufacturer     Cost
XX302          Some Product       ABC Company      750.00
YY110          Another Product    XYZ Company      500.00
etc...
```

This is assuming that ProductID is unique.  That is, you will never have 2 products with the same ID or barcode or whatever you use to catalog your products.  If you may have 2 products with the same ID, then add an ID field in here and set it to AutoNumber.

Lastly, you have the "cross-reference" table, which contains all the Product/Hazard matches:

tblProductHazardCrosswalk:

```
ID      ProductID        HazardID
1       XX302            H101
2       YY110            H101
3       YY110            H102
etc...
```

You put an ID on the last table, because if you ever have to delete or edit a record, it's easier to say "Where ID = 20" than "Where ProductID = XX110 and HazardID = H160".  Once that's lined up, you can use the crosswalk table to join Hazards to Products on both forms and reports.  In fact, you can drop a subform onto your Products form that filters by ProductID, and you can add, edit and delete hazards associated with your products pretty easily.

Always remember; Less is More when it comes to fields.  Don't put 75 fields in a table, or create a table where you have to keep adding fields.  If you're creating your database that way, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time out to write all this. Using a third "cross-reference" table did indeed make things much easier!